# to_xml method and datastore model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working on an academic project which uses google datastore model. I am new to both google app engine and python. Can anyone point to an example of instance method 'to_xml()' of google datastore model class in python? I am kind of stuck and my implementation is not moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a template for your xml. Fill him, as an ordinary template for a html page

```
 Example (first from found)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<!--  If you are running a bot please visit this policy page outlining rules you must respect.         http://www.livejournal.com/bots/  -->
<rss version='2.0' xmlns:lj='http://www.livejournal.org/rss/lj/1.0/' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:atom10='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'>
  <channel>
  <title>Ofertas de empleo en argentina</title>
  <link></link>
<description>'title site'</description>
<lastBuildDate>{{date}}</lastBuildDate>
<generator>'site url'</generator>


{%for i in List%}
<item>
<guid isPermaLink='true'>{{i.url}}</guid>
<pubDate>{{i.date}}</pubDate>
<title>{{i.subject}}</title>
<link>{{i.url}}</link>
<description>{{i.text}}</description>

  </item>
 {%endfor%}

 </channel>
 </rss>
```

About templates cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a `dict` using the `to_dict()` function on [all NDB models](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict). Then use something like [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dicttoxml) to convert to xml

So in your model definition, you can add a function like:

```
import dicttoxml

def to_xml(self):
  return dicttoxml.dicttoxml(self.to_dict())
```

Answer (score 0):

I will start with a general comment. If you are starting out with appengine and python and you intend to develop anything of significance. Stop and start looking at `ndb`. The `to_xml()` method is a feature of the `db` interface, and `ndb` is where the action is, `ndb` solved a number of problems that arise with the complex use of `db`.

Also in your question, you haven't really said what your problem was or what you are trying to achieve.  A bit more clarity may help you get a clear answer - note the wide variety of answers covering very different things.

As to how to use it `to_xml`.

calling .to_xml() will return an xml representation of the entity. It doesn't have a lot of use unless you do want to construct ATOMS of the properties etc..  The docs are here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_to_xml

Here is an example of the us of `to_xml()`

```
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
dev~cash-drawer> class MyClass(db.Model):
...    name = db.StringProperty()
...    value = db.IntegerProperty()
...    state = db.BooleanProperty()
...
dev~cash-drawer> x = MyClass()
dev~cash-drawer> x.name = "hello world"
dev~cash-drawer> x.value = 101
dev~cash-drawer> x.state = False
dev~cash-drawer> x.to_xml()
u'<entity kind="MyClass">\n  <property name="name" type="string">hello world</property>\n  <property name="state" type="bool">False</property>\n  <property name="value" type="int">101</property>\n</entity>\n'
dev~cash-drawer>
```

making it more readable

```
dev~cash-drawer> print x.to_xml()
<entity kind="MyClass">
  <property name="name" type="string">hello world</property>
  <property name="state" type="bool">False</property>
  <property name="value" type="int">101</property>
</entity>
```

Thats all it does.